# "Numeric overflow in expression” manipulating timestamps

Tags: android, exception, numeric

I'm trying to iterate SQL query by setting timestamp to X days earlier with each iteration. I've noticed that my dates are starting to returng nonsense as soon as 25th day back is searched. I've found that Android Studio shows "Numeric overflow in expression" warning for the second row in this code example:

```
int daysBack = 25;
long dayBeginningMilis = getTodaysBeginningMilis() - 86400000 * daysBack;
```

`getTodaysBeginningMilis` is my self-explanatory method. Why does it show this warning? 86400000 is the number of milis in 24 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this part "86400000 * daysBack" causes numeric overflow because both numbers are integers and multiplication causes integer out of bounds. To solve this issue, I've made all numbers of long type:

```
long daysBack = 25L;
long dayBeginningMilis = getTodaysBeginningMilis() - 86400000L * daysBack;
```